# Catch URL with parameters or end of URL using regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to capture some URL patterns with regular expression in Google Analytics, but I have not yet figured out how.

Here are some example URLs:

url1: myurl.com/dir1/dir2

url2: myurl.com/dir1/dir2?myparam=1

url3: myurl.com/dir2/dir2/anotherdir/

I would like to be able to capture the two first ones but not the last one and then the last one but not the two first ones.

I tried for example:
(myurl.com/dir1/dir2$|myurl.com/dir1/dir2?) -> I get url1 but not url2

myurl.com/dir1[^/] -> doesn't work

myurl.com/dir1? -> doesn't work

myurl.com/dir1/ -> capture url 3

So capturing url3 only is easy but I don't see how to capture url1 and url2.

Comment: Try this to match first 2 urls - /myurl\.com\/dir1\/dir2(\?.*)?$/
And this only for 3rd url - myurl\.com\/dir1\/dir2\/.*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, can't you just use this for the first two:

`myurl\.com\/dir1\/dir2($|\?.+)`

And use this for the last:

`myurl\.com\/dir2\/dir2\/.+`

I noticed that you are not using any escape characters. You should escape reserved characters with backslash.

You can use https://regex101.com/ to get detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks! Google Analytics does not need escape characters (at least for /). Your first proposition should work but somehow I don't get any results in Google Analytics while it works with regex101. It's probably not linked to the regular expression then.

Comment: Google Analytics says you do need an escape character for some some of the reserved chars.
https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/regex-google-analytics